# JavaFX: Access .root CSS property from node or scene

Tags: css, javafx

This is a trivial question but searching for CSS in combination with JavaFX always leads to false-positives.
We have a `WebView` and I want to use font color and the accent color we have defined in our JavaFX application for HTML content. In the easiest case, this means we have defined in our FX CSS something like this:

```
.root {
   -color-1: #000;
   -color-2: derive(-color-1, 50%);
}
```

How can I get the values for these properties programmatically from the e.g. the `Scene` object?